# Search Specific Store with eBay API

Tags: php, ebay-api

I have an eBay store that I'd like to be able to Search through JUST that store and return the results.

I found the "findItemsIneBayStores" call, but the documentation is kinda confusing(At least to me) and I can't find a good example so I can see how it works, I was hoping that someone could explain to me how it works.

Thank you,
Brandon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`storeName`](http://developer.ebay.com/Devzone/finding/CallRef/findItemsIneBayStores.html) parameter in your `findItemsIneBayStores` call:

> The name of the eBay store to search. Returns all items in the store, or can be used with keywords to search for specific items in an eBay store. If you do not specify keywords, you must specify storeName.